# Crash the application while click the picture in sunlight in xoce

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm implementing the camera application feature in my iOS App, the problem is when I click the picture in **sunlight** it making my application crash but it is working fine in deamLight.

My code for clicking the pictue

```
        loadingOutlet.hidden=NO;
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate=self;
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self presentViewController: imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil ];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

        CameraPic=YES;
```

and this is for compressing the images when uploading on `UIImageView`

```
-(void)loadImgInNSData
 {
     double size;
     int  compressionRatio=1;
     while ([imgDataCompressImg length]>50000) 
     {
         size = [imgDataCompressImg length];
         compressionRatio=compressionRatio*0.5;
         imgDataCompressImg=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc]  initWithData:imgDataCompressImg],compressionRatio);
         NSLog(@"%i",[imgDataCompressImg length]);
        if (size-[imgDataCompressImg length]<500000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

please help me as soon as possible

Comment: What is your question? Note that a question ends with a `?` and what is **deamLight**?

Answer (score 0):

Increase your image compress length more then 50000 thousand
example like:

```
        [imgDataCompressImg length]>80000

           -(void)loadImgInNSData
             {

              double size;
              int  compressionRatio=1;
              while ([imgDataCompressImg length]>80000) {
              size = [imgDataCompressImg length];
              compressionRatio=compressionRatio*0.5;
              imgDataCompressImg=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc]    initWithData:imgDataCompressImg],compressionRatio);
              NSLog(@"%i",[imgDataCompressImg length]);
              if (size-[imgDataCompressImg length]<800000) {
              break;
              }
            }
```

Comment: It's fine answering your own question but why do you answer it like you are a different person? Should you not be answering it like `I solved this by...` and why is `[imgDataCompressImg length]>80000` out in the middle of nowhere? Makes no sense.